# What are side effects of setPreferredSize?

Tags: java, swing

I have window containing multiple panels. I don't have access to window code. (I can modify only panel’s code.)

I removed few components from panel. Window has shrunk its size. But window is too small to display everything correctly.

I added line `setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());`. Now window have right size.

What are side effects of setPreferredSize?

Edit: BorderLayout is used. Which should ignore getXXXSize(). My panel is in CENTRE. Panel which doesn't fit the screen is on NORTH.

Comment: I dont know side effects but this can help you in understanding setPreferredSize(): set(Preferred/Minimal/Maximum)Size() are nothing more than hints to the parent component and its layoutmanager how much space the component should get.Theses sizes are only interpreted when the components are layouted.

Comment: @Harry True. I should have included layout manager in use. Question have been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is happening:

- `getPreferredSize()` looks whether the size was set before. If not, the method asks the LayoutManager of the component itself (which is your JPanel) about the preferred size, which is then calculated from the components.
- `setPreferredSize(...)` then sets this value on the JPanel, memorizing it for later.
- Later you remove some components of the JPanel.
- Even later, when the window tries to re-layout itself (or is told to do so), the window's (or contentpane's/RootPane's/...) Layoutmanager calls your JPanel's `getPreferredSize()` method again.
- now `getPreferredSize()` does not ask the JPanel's LayoutManager, but simply returns the stored size previously set by `setPreferredSize()`.

<s>For width, the BorderLayout is ignoring the preferred width of the NORTH and south component, it only takes CENTER, EAST and WEST into account. (Similarly for height).</s>

I just took a look at the implementation of `BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize` (in 1.6.0_13 from Sun), and it works like this:

The width is calculated as

```
max(  EAST.width + CENTER.width + WEST.width + h-gaps,
      NORTH.width, SOUTH.width ) + insets
```

The height is calculated as

```
max( EAST.height, CENTER.height, WEST.height)
+ NORTH.height + SOUTH.height + v-gaps + insets
```

(Each of the `width`/`height` are the values of the `preferredSize` of these components.)
If some of the five components are missing, their height/width is not included, neither are the gaps.)

It works the same for `minimalLayoutSize`, while `maximumLayoutSize` simply returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

So, in principle it should work out of the box.

But in general, if the layout of the window is not under your control, you should not have to worry about components not under your control being cut off :-)

Comment: javadoc: "The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over." I missed point that it can be also compressed. :( Right?

Comment: The documentation is not so helpful here ... yes, they are also compressed, if necessary. And the docs of BorderLayout don't describe how the preferred (and minimum/maximum) sizes of the whole container (`preferredLayoutSize()`) are calculated. In fact, it takes in account all components, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it has a lot of effect. The effect depends on

1. the layout manager in use
2. component on which the preferred size is set.

The main reason is that once you call setPreferredSize() to set the size, the component will no more ask ui to get the prefered size. Ideally, only the ui delegate of your component knows the ideal pref size of the component. Once you set the pref size yourself, the ui will not be queried for pref size.

For clarity see the Jcomonent.getPreferredSize() code:

> ```
>     if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
>         return super.getPreferredSize();
>     }
>     Dimension size = null;
>     if (ui != null) {
>         size = ui.getPreferredSize(this);
>     }
> ```

Now why does it depend on layout-manager, because only some layouts call(use) **getPreferredSize()** for computation. For e.g flowlayout uses pref size but border layout doesnt

Comment: Yes, but calling setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize()) after everything was added to my panel shouldn't affect outcome, should it?

Comment: To answer my question in comment: It would. Not visible components doesn't participate in getXXXSize().

Answer (score 0):

Method setPreferredSize() is side effect free.

How getPreferredSize() works was described by Suraj Chandran.

Why setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize()) worked is explained by Paŭlo Ebermann.